# Android: progress bar: three states

Tags: android

Is it possible to have three states in a progress bar?

I know how to set a secondary state, but there is no tertiary state. How do I expand a progress bar to handle that?

greetings, tata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the default system progress bar at [ProgressBar.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java) shows that there is hardcoded limit of two bars at once...

The easiest way for you may probably be copying the progressbar source to your project and add another bar by yourself.

Since there is a secondary progress bar already present, additional ones should not pose any extra difficult challenge (just follow the example of the secondary one).