# Set three parameters for progress bar in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I would like to set three parameters to a progress bar (green color, red color, yellow color).
The default progress bar only allow two colors.

I have a look at this question but of no help. (Im not sure how to edit the ProgressBar.java class)
[Android: progress bar: three states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541930/android-progress-bar-three-states)

Any simpler idea?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, is it possible to make one of the two colours "transparent"?  If so, you could have two progress bars at the same location, where the front one has a transparent portion which allows the back one to show through.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, manage to get it done. I did not make it transparent though, but i stack three progress bars on top of each other and find a workaround to show the colour properly. 